Create gradient with tint color in SwiftUI
When styling a view in SwiftUI, I can use .foregroundStyle to apply a custom shape style, e.g.
view.foregroundStyle(.green)

Besides colors, I can use some more "advanced" shape styles. For example, .tint refers to TintShapeStyle rather than a color and only resolves to a concrete color internally:
view.foregroundStyle(.tint)

If I want to create a gradient for the foreground style, this is easy to do as well using predefined colors:
view.foregroundStyle(.linearGradient(colors: [.blue, .clear], startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom))

Unfortunately, I was not able to figure out how to use "dynamically resolved" colors (such as .tint) when creating a gradient as there is no initializer that accepts a ShapeStyle input (only a list of Color is supported). Is there a way to do this in iOS 17?

You can use .accentColor, .primary and .secondary to build the array of colors. These might translate to the tint color in some cases.

@BenzyNeez unfortunately, .primary and .secondary refer to text colors only and, as you already suggested, .accentColor also does not provide the tint color (even though .accentColor on a view is deprecated in favor of .tint).

".accentColor also does not provide the tint color" It certainly does according to the documentation. Can you show an example where.accentColor is a different color than .tint?

A Shape can be filled with a ShapeStyle and this includes various "semantic colors", including .tint: see Semantic styles.
If you want to fill with a gradient that contains the tint color then what you can do is fill the shape with the tint color first, then overlay with a gradient that uses Color.clear:
struct MyButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .padding(40)
            .background {
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                    .fill(.tint)
                    .fill(
                        .linearGradient(
                            colors: [.clear, .primary],
                            startPoint: .top,
                            endPoint: .bottom
                        )
                    )
            }
    }
}

var body: some View {
    Button("Hello") {}
        .buttonStyle(MyButtonStyle())
        .foregroundStyle(.white)
        .tint(.pink)
}


A similar approach can be used for applying the gradient as a foreground style. A base layer can use .tint as foreground style, an overlay can then show the same content but using a gradient with .clear:
Text("Hello")
    .foregroundStyle(.tint)
    .overlay {
        Text("Hello")
            .foregroundStyle(
                .linearGradient(
                    colors: [.clear, .primary],
                    startPoint: .center,
                    endPoint: .bottom
                )
            )
    }
    .font(.largeTitle)
    .fontWeight(.bold)
    .tint(.pink)


